# Consider the use of double encryption applied to the AES algorithm with two 128-bit keys

Tags: encryption, aes, meet-in-the-middle-attack

Actual Question below.

**Consider the use of double encryption applied to the AES algorithm with two 128-bit keys. How much storage and computation would be required to execute a meet-in-the-middle attack?**

Comment: Your title and question body are asking 2 different questions. 3x128 would take 2.1X the time to encrypt, with 1.5X the key material, for a marginal increase in theoretical security. There is no practical MITM attack against a 128-bit block or key, and probably wont be for a long time. The answer to the storage question is  "a crap load", aka, quadrillions of exabytes

Comment: actually the question like this.

Consider the use of double encryption applied to the AES algorithm with two 128-bit keys. How much storage and computation would be required to execute a meet-in-the-middle attack?

Comment: isn't the question same
http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/44669/used-of-double-encryption-applied-to-the-aes-algorithm-with-two-128bit-key-how-m

Comment: Our generic question on textbook MitM is [Meet-in-the-middle with checking complexity](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/10068/555), though it is in the context of DES and the answer needs adaptation. For techniques with feasibly much memory, there's [Can cycle finding techniques reduce the memory usage of the MitM attack against 2DES](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/25258/555), but it only comes with an arguably hairy answer of mine, that was not accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Double encryption applied to the AES-128 algorithm and two random keys is theoretically breakable from 3 plaintext/ciphertext pairs by the generic [Meet-in-the-Middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meet-in-the-middle_attack) with 2<sup>128</sup> encryptions for building a dictionary, and an expected 2<sup>127</sup> attempts each requiring a about one decryption and two encryptions (the later is for checking an average of one candidate key pair). This totals to an expected 5⋅2<sup>127</sup> AES-128 operations. That's so large as to be currently impossible: the realm of feasibility nowadays stops somewhere a 2<sup>75</sup> to 2<sup>100</sup>, with the later acknowledged good to 2020 by many authorities. Thus we have a margin like a thousand millions, which I guess is fine for a good two decades, save for fairies or imminent breakthrough in quantum computers making them useful for such tasks.

The amount of memory required for the schoolbook MitM attack is 2<sup>128</sup> words each 128-bit, that is 2<sup>135</sup> bits. Nowadays, a silicon wafer is seldom less than <strike>80µm</strike> 50µm thick (these are used in Smart Cards, and obtained by milling normal wafers rather than by using [ultra-thin wafers](https://www.virginiasemi.com/?cont_uid=18)), a DRAM cell occupies an area of at least 4F<sup>2</sup> with feature size F=10nm, thus we are talking 0.9⋅10<sup>21</sup>m<sup>3</sup> of silicon; that's 80% of the volume of earth, which contains only 15% silicon. Quick, make these wafers even thinner or (more realistically) start making 3D silicon that is not stacked wafers!

There is a well-known refinement of MitM that requires a feasible amount RAM, but more computation than the generic MitM. See Paul C. van Oorschot and Michael J. Wiener: [*Parallel Collision Search with Cryptanalytic Applications*](https://people.scs.carleton.ca/%7Epaulv/papers/JoC97.pdf) (in [Journal of Cryptology](https://doi.org/10.1007/PL00003816), 1999).

Interestingly, it is not known any generic technique that uses moderate amount of RAM and breaks two-key triple encryption of some *b*-bit block cipher with cost commensurate to 2<sup>*b*</sup> or even 2<sup>3 *b* /2</sup> encryptions.

Answer (score 0):

fgrieu answered this in a footnote [elsewhere](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/26235/6417):

---

Double AES with two 128 bit keys would be significantly slower than single AES with a 256 bit key (20 rounds versus 14). Also double AES-128 would theoretically be vulnerable to a [Meet-in-the-Middle attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/26235/6417), when AES-256 is not.

---

So how much storage and computation a meet-in-the-middle attack would take doesn't matter as there is no real reason to be using double AES-128 (as it's slower and probably weaker than AES-256).

Comment: Depending on what you need to do, AES-256 may also be subject to some weaknesses. AES-192 and AES-256 have related key attacks that AES-128 do not have. A related question here https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1549/related-key-attacks-on-aes